# IF Null exit sub code

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to check that if cells are empty or null, that it would display a message and exit sub. Here's my code:

```
With Worksheets(1).[D3:D4, D6:D14]
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Nothing to generate" & vbNewLine & _
        "Set parameters and click generate."
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
```

But the code only works if the entire `[D3:D4, D6:D14]` are empty. I want it to exit sub even just one of the cells are empty. All cells needs have content for it to continue sub. Please help.

Comment: try the code below

Comment: then use `.CountBlank(` instead of `.CountA(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `SpecialCells`:

```
Sub Check()
Dim rng1 As Range
On Error Resume Next

With Worksheets(1).[D3:D4, D6:D14]
Set rng1 = .SpecialCells(xlBlanks)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing to generate" & vbNewLine & _
        "Set parameters and click generate."
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

*Follow-up question*

```
Sub Check2()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

With Worksheets(1)
Set rng1 = .Range(.[D3:D4], .[D6:D14])
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set rng2 = rng1.SpecialCells(xlBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox rng1.Cells.Count - rng2.Cells.Count & " were used"
Else
    MsgBox "all cells used"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks! A follow up though, the current message displaying is if the entire `[D3:D4, D6:D14]` is `Nothing` but I want to display a different message to complete the parameters if 1 cell but not all has content. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to seach inside the Range, try the code below:

```
Sub CheckEmptyCellsinRange()

Dim Rng     As Range
Dim cell    As Range

Set Rng = Worksheets(1).[D3:D4, D6:D14]

For Each cell In Rng
    If IsEmpty(cell) Or IsNull(cell) Then
        MsgBox "Nothing to generate" & vbNewLine & _
        "Set parameters and click generate."
        Exit Sub        
    End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Looping cell by cell can by expensive time wise for large ranges

Comment: you're right, but in his example he has a range of less than 10 cells